# Squirrel SQL Client UI remains hidden

Tags: java, squirrel-sql

Since I keep getting the log message to add

```
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

to the JAVA_OPTS for the squirrel bat file, I finally added the argument and started Squirrel.

Now the Squirrel-SQL client shows a weird behavior.

The SQL Client starts without errors in the console window (where I invoke it by using squirrel-sql.bat; however I don't see any UI even though the splach screen shows up momentarily.

I can see the process still running in the background using process explorer.

I have tried removing the -Dsun.java2d.noddraw option from the java option but to no luck.

Any body else encountered similar issue?

```
System Info:

Windows 7, enterprise edition, 64 bit.
java version "1.6.0_37"
```